# Type 'Any' has no subscript members when accessing dictionary in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am trying to access the values of a dictionary which I passed into `UserDefaults`, however I get this error:

> **Type 'Any' has no subscript members**.

I have looked around on StackOverflow for answers but everything I tried is failing.

This is the Dictionary object that I stored in UserDefaults and I am trying to access `Authorities.levelAcess`:

```
{
       accountEnabled = 0;
        accountLocked = 0;
        Authorities =     {
            levelAccess = "tier2";
            accessType = "3rd party";
        };
        message = "Logged in Successfully";
        profile = "trust";
        roles =     (
                    {
                authority = "admin";
            }
        );
        status = 1;
}
```

This the code for UserDefaults:

```
 let keyDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = json
 UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "dict")
```

This is how I am trying to access the dictionary:

[image]

Comment: You should add code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of showing this error in your code is: the compiler *cannot* recognize `result` as dictionary, if you tried to <kbd>option</kbd> and click on `result` you would see that its type is `Any`. You have to cast it first as `[String: AnyObject]` and then get "Authorities" form it.

It should be like this:

```
if let result = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "dict") {
    print(result)
}
```

That's how you should "optional binding" the dictionary, thus (assumeing that "Authorities" is a `[String: String]`):

```
if let addresses = result["Authorities"] as? [String: String] {
    print(addresses)
}
```

You could also do it as one step:

```
if let result = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "dict"),
   let addresses = result["Authorities"] as? [String: String] {
    print(result)
    print(addresses)

    let levelAccess = addresses["levelAccess"]
    print(levelAccess) // optional
}
```

Finally, you could get the `levelAcess` from `addresses` as:

```
let levelAccess = addresses["levelAccess"]
```

Again, note that `levelAccess` would be an `optional` string (`String?`), which means you should also handle it.

Comment: Exceptional , Thank you very much extremely  well explained, im gratefulll

Comment: It should **not** be `value(forKey` in this case, never. Please stop suggesting this inappropriate KVC method unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC. There is a `dictionary(forKey` method

Comment: @vadian thanks for the note. Could you please elaborate? 

Comment: `value(forKey` is a method with a special functionality. This functionality has got more overhead and is absolutely not necessary when getting a dictionary from user defaults. `UserDefaults` has dedicated methods for many different types.

Comment: Oh, my bad! got it... Edited.

Comment: when i test this code it  gets to **let addresses = result["Authorities"] as? [String: String] {** then steps out nothing gets printed

Comment: This error is printed in the console : warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: @Erent could you try the updated answer (all in one step code)?

Comment: I figured what the error was , Thanks @AhmadF  The error was on my code which is not part of this question. All is working now thank you

Comment: @vadian Thank you for the comments i am grateful to have attained more indepth knowledge on how things work

Answer (score 1):

For fetching a dictionary from UserDefaults, use

```
dictionary(forKey: key)
```

In your case:

```
var result = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "dict")
```